# Changing AWS EMR's Yarn Scheduler to FIFO gives Invalid resource request

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I changed AWS EMR's YARN Scheduler by adding the following xml code to /etc/hadoop/config/yarn-site.xml

```
 <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
 <value>true</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fifo.FifoScheduler</value>
 </property>
```

Now when I run spark-submit for my jar, following errors appear:

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidLabelResourceRequestException: Invalid resource request, queue=default doesn't have permission to access all labels in resource request. labelExpression of resource request=CORE. Queue labels=
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.validateResourceRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerUtils.normalizeAndValidateRequest(SchedulerUtils.java:257)
    at ...
```

The scheduler has switched succesfully to FIFO as seen in this Image:
[image]

So can anyone explain whats the error here?

Comment: Can you please add fair-scheduler.xml

Comment: I am trying to implement fifo scheduler,so won't that be fifo-scheduler.xml? and where can I get guide to that?